# Show text for particular points of line chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to show text for points that have only the maximum and minimum values so I can avoid text overlapping as shown in the image.

[image]

Here is the code

```
x = df['Measurement Date']
y = df['SYS']
  
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 10)

for x, y in zip(df['Measurement Date'], df['SYS']):
    plt.text(x = x, y = y, s = '{:.0f}'.format(y))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you provide a example of your dataframe?

Comment: Could you please download it from kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/rjalexander/blood-pressure-readings

Comment: You can do this by creating a data frame that extracts the maximum and minimum values from the data frame, and replace the target of the loop processing with that data. `min_max = df[(df['SYS'] == df['SYS'].min()) | (df['SYS'] == df['SYS'].max())];for x, y in zip(min_max['Measurement Date'], min_max['SYS']):`

Comment: It works Thank you!! you can add it as an answer so I can choose it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by looping through the data frame with the minimum and maximum values extracted from the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('./data/bp_log.csv')
min_max = df[(df['SYS'] == df['SYS'].min()) | (df['SYS'] == df['SYS'].max())] 
x = df['Measurement Date']
y = df['SYS']
  
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15, 10)

#for x, y in zip(df['Measurement Date'], df['SYS']):
for x, y in zip(min_max['Measurement Date'], min_max['SYS']):
    plt.text(x = x, y = y, s = '{:.0f}'.format(y))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the opportunity to respond.

Comment: you r welcome!!